# Match an entire field

Tags: elasticsearch

For the query: `'goodbye cruel world'` and a field called 'title'.
Let's say I have the documents:

```
1. {'title': 'goodbye cruel'}   
2. {'title': 'goodbye world'}   
3. {'title': 'cruel world'}   
4. {'title': 'goodbye cruel world'}   
5. {'title': 'goodbye very cruel world'}
6. {'title': 'hello cruel world'}
```

I want a query to match documents 1, 2, 3, 4 but not 5 or 6, because they don't have all the terms in the query.

(I asked a similar looking question before and it was answered correctly, but it was not what I actually  wanted to asked so I'm submitting this as a different question)

Comment: i'm confused only 4& 5 has all the terms rest do not ? do you mean to say you want to match 4 and 5  ?

Comment: 5 has the word 'very' which is not in the query.

Comment: you may need to do a post analysis after getting the results back from ES. there's no analyzer out of the box that can do this.